# How can I do pagination with MVC Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, pagination

How can I do pagination with MVC Razor?
Recommended to use of Page Helper. But not appears as extensions (nuget) in my visual web developer.
How do I do pagination without Page Helper?

Comment: @Hadas, is use Jquery Pagination plugin?But is enough only the plugin?

Comment: I dont know how you write your code. I send to a partial view the first lines. In plugin I send ajax request with the number of page, return from the server the next lines to a partial and replace the two partials with jquery.